# Assignin the output of a function as an input to another one c++

Tags: c++, function

Hi I want to know how can I assign an output as an input to another function. Below there is an example.

I want to fully explain my assignment:

- I have a string with operands and numbers.
- I splited it into 3 numbers being "num1" "num2" and "ans" with a function.
- Now I need another function to sum "num1" and "num2" and another function to check if the real answer and the user answer are equal.
- For this I need to input num1 and num2 into another function and I couldn't manage how to do that.

  ```
  int step1()
  {
     int x = 12;
     int new_x = 2*12;
     return new_x;
  }

  int step2()
  {
     sqr_x = new_x * new_x
     return sqr_x;
  }
  ```

Comment: The second function should be declared with a parameter.

Comment: `sqr_x = step1() * step1();` ?

Comment: It's not clear to me how you wish to use the functions in your posted code.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen it was just an example I'm working with something more complex.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow like int step ( new_x){} ?

Comment: @MehmetPancaroglu The name of a parameter can be any as you like. For example int step( int x ){ /*... */. }

Comment: Do you mean take a function pointer as an argument to another function?

Comment: You can call `step1(step2())`, which will call `step1()` with the return value of `step2()` (note that you'll need an input parameter to `step1`)

Comment: One potential problem is that you use _global_ variables that are unknown entities to us. They could be `Smurf` or `int` or `std::string` or `spaceship`. Minimize the use of globals and it's easier to present the problem.

Comment: Are you simply asking how to use parameters in a function? `int retValue(int A) { return A + 2; }` is this example what you are looking for?

Comment: You should perhaps review the notes from learning in class how to use functions, or else discuss with your teacher for clarification if they were not clear. That's what they're there for! Ask your teacher to go over the function part of the course again

Answer (score 0):

If you pass an argument you can do this. You could also declare the `new_x` variable at the top of your program, but to keep it the way you did this kinda, call the function

```cpp
int step1() {
   int x = 12;
   int new_x = 2*x;
   return new_x;
}

int step2() {
   int sqr_x = step1()*step1()
   return sqr_x;
}
```

Comment: You do not pass any argument.